# How to make local function binding for closure?

Tags: elisp, defun, lexical-binding, closures

For example, when defining the natural number sequence stream, I can use

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun nats (n)
  (cons n (lambda () (nats (1+ n)))))

(nats 0)
     => (0 closure ((n . 0) t) nil (nats (1+ n)))
```

But I want to call simply `(nats)` since the natural numbers begins with `0`, and I don't want define a global helper function for `nats` since it is useless everywhere else. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defalias 'nats
  (flet ((f (n) (cons n (lambda () (f (1+ n))))))
    (lambda () (f 0))))

(nats)
error--> nats: Symbol's function definition is void: f
```

It looks like `f` is not in the closure's environment. I also tried some other options. `cl-letf` produces the same result. `cl-flet` doesn't allow recursive local function definition.

Comment: If you want a recursive local function, you can use `letrec` (a newish Elisp construct) or `cl-labels`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without `cl-lib`:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun nats ()
  (letrec ((inner (lambda (n) (cons n (lambda () (funcall inner (1+ n)))))))
    (funcall inner 0)))

(let* ((stream (nats))
       (i (car stream)))
  (while (< i 10)
    (message "Got %i" i)
    (setq stream (funcall (cdr stream))
          i (car stream))))
```

See also https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/issues/39#issuecomment-129636221.  As suggested in the linked post, I'd generally recommend against writing such code and going for a top-level helper function instead.  Emacs Lisp isn't Scheme after all, so you're only going to confuse whoever may read your code...

Comment: Thanks, it looks this is a very straightforward but correct solution. There is an issue with `defun`: once `nats` is called, `inner` is globally accessible, I guess `makunbound` can be used to fix it.

Comment: Huh, that shouldn't happen.  Either I'm wrong about this solution or there's a bug in the lexical binding code...

Comment: Anyway, I've replaced it with an alternative solution that doesn't require `cl-lib`.

Comment: `defun` always makes global bindings, it expands to `defalias` which is like `fset`. `letrec` is the right choice here.

Comment: +1 (especially for the recommendation and reminder that Emacs Lisp is not Scheme).

Comment: You also need another `funcall` for `inner` in the innermost lambda. Now I see, for something like `(let ((inner (lambda () (funcall inner ...)))) (funcall inner))`, `let` works for dynamic environment and `letrec` works for lexical environment.

Comment: Ugh, I must have had another `inner` left over from my previous attempts.  Fixed.